# Как добавить столбец в существующую таблицу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Есть такая база данных

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(BigInteger)
    balance = Column(Float, default=1)
```

Хочу добавить в нее например параметр бонус, при этом не стирая базу. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4253879/2101808

Comment: Погуглить что такое миграции. В частности `alembic`. Можно сделать также через чистый sql.